# Dynamically created User Control detecting button click from main Form

Tags: c#, user-controls, detect, buttonclick, eventhandler

I have been trying to figure this out for the better part of two days and have searched everywhere to find a solution, so if this is easily answered I apologize up front. Also, I am fairly new to c# and programming in general.

I have a [form](/questions/tagged/form) wherein one button creates a new [usercontrol](/questions/tagged/usercontrol). This user control has a listview (for now, at some point I'm probably going to change this to a datagridview) that is updated with information from an Access database. When another button (Save) on the Form is clicked, information is added to the database. I would like for my UserControl to detect when the Save button is clicked and update the listview.

Below is a sample from my code, trimmed down to what I hope are the important bits.

Form stuff.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler saveClick;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Stuff happens here that saves all input to the database
        if (this.saveClick != null)
            this.saveClick(this, e);            
    }

    //Creates the UserControl TodayCallHistory as tch and expands Form1 window to accomodate the new control
    private void butListShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!expanded)
        {
            expanded = true;
            butListShow.Text = "\u25C0";
            TodayCallHistory tch = new TodayCallHistory();
            tch.Name = "tch";
            tch.SetParentForm(this); //This was added per the answer below
            List<int> pos = new List<int>();
            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                int right = x.Right;
                pos.Add(right);
            }
            tch.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(pos.Max() + 10, 10);
            formWidth = this.Width;
            this.Width = this.Width + tch.Width + 10;
            this.Controls.Add(tch);
        }
        else
        {
            expanded = false;
            butListShow.Text = "\u25B6";
            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x.Name == "tch")
                    this.Controls.Remove(x);
            }
            this.Width = formWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl stuff.

```
public partial class TodayCallHistory : UserControl
{
    private Form1 frm = new Form1();

    public TodayCallHistory()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //frm.saveClick += new EventHandler(saveWasClicked); Removed based on answer below
    }

    //This following part was added per the marked answer below
    public void SetParentForm(Form1 parent)
    {
        frm = parent;
        frm.saveClick += new EventHandler(saveWasClicked);
    }

    private void saveWasClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshList();
    }

    private void refreshList()
    {
        //Sends query to database and then populates a listview with this information
    }
}
```

When the Save button is clicked on the Form, nothing happens on the UserControl. Just a big ole pile of nothing. If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or a better way to approach this, I would be extremely grateful! I can also post more of my code if I'm not sharing enough.

EDIT 1: I should also mention that this is a WinForm, written in c# using Visual Studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop.

EDIT 2: Added my code for creating the UserControl when a button is clicked on Form1. The same button also removes the control. Basically I wanted to have an "expand window" (I have no idea what the actual term should be) feature as part of my Form1.

EDIT 3: Using Harrison Paine's (not sure how to tag a username) suggestion below, I added the SetParentForm method to the UserControl. Since my UserControl isn't created until the button click on Form1, I had to add the SetParentForm on Form1 after it was created.

Right after

```
tch.Name = "tch";
```

I added

```
tch.SetParentForm(this);
```

EDIT 4: So as to avoid creating a new Form1, I made the following changes.

Form1

```
public static event EventHandler saveClick; //Added static modifier 

public void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Stuff happens here that saves all input to the database
    if (Form1.saveClick != null)
        Form1.saveClick(this, e); //Changed this.saveClick to Form1.saveClick 
}

private void butListShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
tch.Parent = this; //All the other stuff from above, plus this now
}
```

I changed `this.saveClick` to `Form1.saveClick` since it is has the static modifier (I mostly guessed I had to do this and am still working on understanding exactly what 'static' does hah)

UserControl

```
    public TodayCallHistory()
    {
        Form1.saveClick += new EventHandler(saveWasClicked);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I removed the `Form1 frm = new Form1();` as well as the entire `SetParentForm` method.

For those wondering why I didn't just have the UserControl created and always there, with just a `.Visible` set to `True` or `False`, I determined after much reading that the "better practice" is to create and destroy controls as you need them, especially if you have a lot of them on a form. If I'm completely off-base/insane on this, please let me know so I can take the easy way out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `TodayCallHistory` is creating its own `Form1` and listening to an event on that object.

You need to pass in the actual `Form1` that has the user control and then register the event handler on that object.

Something like this:

In `TodayCallHistory.cs`:

```
public void SetParentForm(Form1 parent)
{
    frm = parent;
    frm.SaveClick += new EventHandler(saveWasClicked);
}
```

In `Form1.cs`:

```
public Form1
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.myTodayCallHistory.SetParentForm(this);
}
```

---

The issue stems from the following:

```
public partial class TodayCallHistory : UserControl
{
    private Form1 frm = new Form1();
```

The `Form1` created here is an entirely different object than the "original" one, whose save button you are clicking.  Instead of creating a brand new object, you need to pass the original one in somehow.  The `SetParentForm()` method is just one way to do this.

Comment: I get the following error for the "this.tch.SetParentForm(this);" part... 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'tch' and no extension method 'tch' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have updated my code above to also show my creation of the UserControl as it does not exist prior to the button click. Is this possibly the problem?

Comment: I figured it out with your help - THANK YOU SO MUCH! I just needed to move your SetParentForm part to after the UserControl was created. Seriously, this was driving me nuts as to why it wasn't working and I can't thank you enough for giving me a straight forward, easy to understand, and detailed answer. I'll now be researching how exactly parent forms work.

Comment: @koosh "Parent form" isn't an actual concept.  The issue in your case is that you created two different instances of `Form1`: The first one contains an instance of your `TodayCallHistory` which, it its constructor, creates a new instance of `Form1` called `frm`.  The object that named `frm` is the same _type_, but not the same object.
The `SetParentForm()` method I proposed is just a way to give `TodayCallHistory` a reference to a `Form1`.  I'll update the answer to make this a little more clear.

Comment: That makes sense to me. What is a proper way to pass the original Form1 into the UserControl? Using your code above, if I remove the 'private Form1 frm = new Form1();' it starts throwing errors (frm is no longer recognized). Creating a new Form1 seems silly so I would rather do it "right" than the slapjob it appears I have created.

Comment: I think I sorta maybe kinda understand passing parent form schtoof to my UserControl ("child form"?). See EDIT 4 above.